# Why does FileWriter overwrite the file even though I did specify it should append

Tags: java

This is what I have:

```
try{
    String filename = "Names.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
    BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    buffer.append("NAME: " + name + " AGE: " + age + " ID: " + id + "\n\n");

    System.out.println("We have succefully created your account.");
    buffer.close();
    start();
} catch(IOException e){
    System.err.println("ERROR");
}
```

It always overwrites the first line and does not go to a different one. I've used the append. This is my start method:

```
// this is the start method
public static void start(){
    System.out.println("1) Add Account 2) Exit");
    System.out.println("What do you want to do: ");
    stuff = input.nextInt();

    if (stuff == 1) {
        try {
            x = new Formatter("Names.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR" );
        }
        newRecord();
    } else if(stuff == 2) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, Thanks

Comment: It still overwrites the top line

Comment: newRecord just asks the user to input their name, age, and id number

Comment: Can you post [a (short) complete code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with exact instruction how to reproduce it on our side, including how you're looking at the contents of the file? I strongly doubt the problem is with the posted code.

Comment: I did test it, it didn't work, ill edit this and paste all of the code in

Comment: Here's the code http://pastebin.com/cRPbLDfY

Comment: @shmcrae You should visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should not **drastically** change your question, instead if you have another problem, ask another question (and maybe link this one), but **do not modify a question to ask another question** !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess is this line:

```
x = new Formatter("Names.txt");
```

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String))

> `public Formatter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException`
>
> Parameters:
>
> fileName - The name of the file to use as the destination of this formatter. **If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

(I add emphasis to the part that is cleaning your file).

Comment: Thank you soo much. that was the problem, thanks again

Comment: @shmcrae You don't need to clarify that you solved your problem in the question. if some of the answer here helps you, add a +1 to the answer, if also answer your question, then click the tick. :)!